# Disposing disposable dependencies with Windows desktop applications

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, desktop-application

We all know that we should dispose of disposable objects once we have finished using them. The question is: If I have a disposable object (eg. a database context) being used throughout the entire lifetime of a windows desktop application (e.g. WPF or WinForms): Should I dispose of that object in the application shutdown event (why, when, when not)?

Comment: Your database context *shouldn't* live for the entire lifetime of your application.  They're not designed to be long lived objects.  You should be re-creating them when you perform each DB operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a rule, you should avoid having disposable objects that live for the lifetime of your application.  Many objects, such as database contexts, just *shouldn't* be used at that scope.

If you really do need to do it though, it depends on whether or not the object "properly" implements the IDisposable pattern.  If the disposable object implements a finalizer then it will be disposed when the application ends even if you don't call `Dispose` on it.  If the object doesn't implement a finalizer you will need to dispose of it when the application is shutting down unless the resource that it would leak is a non-issue.  For example, if it would be leaking memory that will be shut down when the process ends, there's no need to release it, if it is only going to be unsubscribing from events there's no need for it to run, etc.  If you are unsure of what *exactly* is being released in the `Dispose` method then you should be safe and call it anyway.

Comment: There are a couple of points i don't understand in your answer, the first about the database context, if my application uses a local db (eg. SQL CE) why do i need to dispose the context with every operation, plus i have my contexts injected through an IoC where they are declared singletones. The second point where you talk about the process shutdown, when a process is shutting down, does it reclaim every resource used by the application, be that a memory section, file, db, etc ... and if that is the case, why dispose of those resources. Thanks

Comment: @Sniffer No, when a process is shutting down it won't always be able to reclaim the resources that a dispose method will.  Unless you specifically know that all resources reclaimined in the Dispose method  happen automatically when the process is torn down, you should dispose of it.  As for the database context; you're tying up a lot of resources keeping it open all of the time.  It's *designed* to be a short lived object used for a single transaction.