# Short-living DbContext with desktop applications and a local database

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, sql-server-ce, desktop-application

This question was inspired by an earlier question i have asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14817102/disposing-disposable-dependencies-with-windows-desktop-applications/), I have learned from that question that DbContext instances should be short living dependencies. Now given that i develop LOB desktop applications with local databases using SQL CE i have a few questions:

1. In my case (local db, single user, desktop app), should DbContext really live for a short-period of time ?
2. if i disposed of my DbContext with every operation, would that make me lose all the tracking information gathered through out its life cycle ?
3. if the answer to 2 is true (trouble!), how to go about doing it the right way, should i develop a UnitOfWork that keeps change tracking information or what ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Yes, short is good. But every user input/interaction is extreme

**2)** Clearly yes.  But beyond a logical unit of work from a Client interaction, the pattern of discarding the context fits in well.  eg Change an order.   Perhaps Header, Items and cust loaded. New address added to cust, Order header changed and SaveChanges.  New logical interactions starts on client.  Dont forget you can have several smaller contexts. Indeed bounded contexts are key to performance.   Perhaps you have 1 long running context with system config and other such settings that are non volatile, few in number but accessed very often.   I would keep such a context for longer.

**3)**Not sure exactly what the question is.   But  a LUW type of Class that has a method Commit and then disposes the context is 1 such pattern.

Dont forget to generate Views on DbContexts if reloaded often.

Comment: Can you please explain your last suggestion, "Don't forget to generate view ...", and i don't know if you work at Microsoft or not, but if this whole code first thing was developed to help out DDD developers, and since the DbContext represents a UoW that keeps track of things, then disposing of it wouldn't really give it any benefit: i mean it won't be doing one of the most important thing a UoW should be doing: Change Tracking. Thank you for your help.

Comment: sure: if you havent already, install the entity framework powertools. http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d     then on your DB context class right click, you should see a content menu option Entity framework.  Inside there is the Generate view option.   It generates a class inside the project. This class has an embed in assembly instruction. This makes first access to dbsets faster.  There are some good performance tips here at this MS EF site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/cc853327.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your explanation about the first part of the question, can i get your comment please about the other part ?

Comment: On the Self tracking.... let EF do that for you.  EF will unless you switch it off, track Loaded entities and changes there of.  If you want to know what has changed, there a few tools/suggestions on SO on how to find out what has chnaged.

Answer (score 2):

Old quesiton, but it can help to someone maybe.

As described in [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowshardware/en-US/ee58c0ec-8899-4b57-bf63-4a2c89d43523/short-lived-dbcontext-in-wpf-application-reasonable?forum=adodotnetentityframework) article, the living of the dbContext object depends weather it is used in web or desktop app.

Web Application

- It is now a common and best practice that for web applications,
  context is used per request.
- In web applications, we deal with requests that are very short but
  holds all the server transaction they are therefore the proper
  duration for the context to live in.

Desktop Applications

- ***For desktop application, like Win Forms/WPF, etc. the context is used
  per form/dialog/page.***
- Since we don’t want to have the context as a singleton for our
  application we will dispose it when we move from one form to another.
- In this way, we will gain a lot of the context’s abilities and won’t
  suffer from the implications of long running contexts.

Basically, context should be short living object, but always with the right balance.